# CSS float mosaic - issue with text centering

Tags: html, css

I have created simple float based banner with tiles like this:

[My code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa30ek53/),
but I have a big problem with centering text in each tile. I would like to have all "Sample text" texts centered in each tile (horizontally and vertically) but I have no idea how to achieve that..

I have tried many methods but text is never centered well. How can I do that?

I will also paste my code here:
HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="page-content">
          <div id="banner-wrapper">
            <div class="column left-col">

              <div class="block block-25">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                  <div class="block-content">Sample text</div>
              </div>

              <div class="block block-24">
                <div class="block-content">Sample text</div>
              </div>

              <div class="block block-22">
                <div class="block-content">Sample text</div>
              </div>

              <div class="block block-21">
                <div class="block-content">Sample text</div>
              </div>
            </div> <!--Column left END -->
            <div class="column right-col">

              <div class="block block-23">
                <div class="block-content">Sample text</div>
              </div>
            </div><!--Column right END -->
          </div> <!--Banner wrapper END -->
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
body {font-family:  margin:0;}
#page-content {max-width: 1220px; margin: 0 auto; position:relative;}

/* banner */
#banner-wrapper {overflow:hidden; padding:0px; margin: 0px;}
.column {height:442px;float:left;}
#banner-wrapper .left-col {width: 65.5%}
#banner-wrapper .right-col {width:34.5%}

.horizontal-line-top {height:4px; background-color: #3e7213; border: 0px;}
.horizontal-line-bottom {height:4px; background-color: #609732; border: 0px;}

.block {position:relative;float:left;box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; border: 2px solid #fff;}
.block-25 {background-color:blue;border-left: 0px;border-top:0px; width:40%; height:50%;}
.block-24 {width:60%;background-color:blue; height:50%;border-top:0px; }
.block-22 {border-bottom:0px; border-left: 0px;width:28%;;background-color:blue; height:50%;}
.block-21 {border-bottom:0px;width:72%;background-color:blue; height:50%;}
.block-23 {border-right: 0px;width:100%;background-color:blue; height:100%;border-top:0px; border-bottom:0px;}

.block-content { position: absolute;color:#fff;visibility:hidden;float:none; margin:0 auto;}

.block:hover > .overlay {float:left; width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#000;opacity:0.5;}
.block:hover .block-content {visibility:visible;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this css. This will solve the problem.

```
.block-content{
position: relative; 
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I tried it putting inline. If you are putting it in the external sheet then watch for contradictions. This is working well.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But could you explain why I have to use translate?

Comment: It has been used to scale the content automatically according to the div size. This will make the text responsive,i.e this property directs the other properties to how to work in different sized <div>

Answer (score 1):

Simple one! [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aa30ek53/1/)

Just add `width:100%;` and give `text-align:center;`

```
.block:hover .block-content {
    visibility: visible;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text into a `span` element and display it as a block element. Then you can center the element using the `transform` property. Please have a look at my code:

```css
body {font-family:  margin:0;}
#page-content {max-width: 1220px; margin: 0 auto; position:relative;}

/* banner */
#banner-wrapper {overflow:hidden; padding:0px; margin: 0px;}
.column {height:442px;float:left;}
#banner-wrapper .left-col {width: 65.5%}
#banner-wrapper .right-col {width:34.5%}

.horizontal-line-top {height:4px; background-color: #3e7213; border: 0px;}
.horizontal-line-bottom {height:4px; background-color: #609732; border: 0px;}

.block {position:relative;float:left;box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; border: 2px solid #fff;}
.block-25 {background-color:blue;border-left: 0px;border-top:0px; width:40%; height:50%;}
.block-24 {width:60%;background-color:blue; height:50%;border-top:0px; }
.block-22 {border-bottom:0px; border-left: 0px;width:28%;;background-color:blue; height:50%;}
.block-21 {border-bottom:0px;width:72%;background-color:blue; height:50%;}
.block-23 {border-right: 0px;width:100%;background-color:blue; height:100%;border-top:0px; border-bottom:0px;}

.block-content { position: absolute;color:#fff;visibility:hidden;float:none; margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:100%;}

.block-content span { display:block; position:relative; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%); text-align:center }

.block:hover > .overlay {float:left; width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#000;opacity:0.5;}
.block:hover .block-content {visibility:visible;}
```

```html
  <div id="page-content">
          <div id="banner-wrapper">
            <div class="column left-col">

              <div class="block block-25">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                  <div class="block-content"><span>Sample Text</span></div>
              </div>

              <div class="block block-24">
                <div class="block-content"><span>Sample Text</span></div>
              </div>

              <div class="block block-22">
                <div class="block-content"><span>Sample Text</span></div>
              </div>

              <div class="block block-21">
                <div class="block-content"><span>Sample Text</span></div>
              </div>
            </div> <!--Column left END -->
            <div class="column right-col">

              <div class="block block-23">
                <div class="block-content"><span>Sample Text</span></div>
              </div>
            </div><!--Column right END -->
          </div> <!--Banner wrapper END -->
    </div>
```